# How to plot secondary y axis BEHIND primary y axis using Plotly in R?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm wondering how I may adjust my below example code so the secondary *y* axis - which is a filled area chart - is plotted behind the bars (primary *y* axis) in `ploty`. Thanks.

```
library(plotly)

day <- c(1:20)
load <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 500, sd = 80)
mon <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 2, sd = 0.2)

d <- data.frame(day, load, mon)

plot_ly(d) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~day,
            y = ~mon,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "lines",
            fill = "tonexty",
            yaxis = "y2",
            name = "Mon") %>%
  add_trace(x = ~day,
            y = ~load,
            type = "bar",
            name = "Session") %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right"))
```

[image]